# Test class for @future method called by trigger not working (Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts)

Tags: trigger, unit-test, callout, future, httpcalloutmock

I have a trigger on Account that makes a call to an apex class:

```
trigger AccountAddressTrigger on Account (after insert) {

Id patientAccountRecordTypeId = [SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Patient_Account'].Id;


      for(account a:trigger.new){
        if( trigger.isInsert &&
            a.PersonMailingStreet != null &&
            a.PersonMailingCity != null &&
            a.RecordTypeId == patientAccountRecordTypeId &&
           personAccountsGeoCoder.isFirstTime){
               System.debug('isInsert');
            personAccountsGeoCoder.isFirstTime = false;
            personAccountsGeoCoder.updatePersonAccount(a.Id); //this is the apex class
        }
    }
}
```

the Apex class : personAccountsGeoCoder then makes a callout using Salesforce's maps API. I go over the response and then grab the latitude and longitude values from the response and put them into the account record and do a DML update.

```
public class personAccountsGeoCoder {
    public static Boolean isFirstTime = true;
    
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void updatePersonAccount(Id accountToUpdate) { 
    // Create and add an address.
    Account a = [SELECT Id, PersonMailingStreet, PersonMailingCity,PersonMailingState, PersonMailingPostalCode, PersonMailingCountry FROM Account WHERE Id =: accountToUpdate];
    string shippingAddress = a.PersonMailingStreet+ a.PersonMailingCity + a.PersonMailingState + a.PersonMailingPostalCode+ a.PersonMailingCountry;

    Map<string,object> options = new Map<String,Object> {
                'version' => '1', // Required. Version of the API endpoint. Must be '1'.
                'address' => shippingAddress
            };
    
    // Call the Geocode() method with the address.
    Map<String, Object>response = maps.API.Geocode(options); //this is the web callout 
    
    System.debug('::response::' + response);
    // Log the resulting geographical coordinates and formatted address. 
    
    Map<String, Object> response2 = (Map<String, Object>) response.get('data');
    System.debug('::response2::' + response2);
    Map<String, Object> response3 = (Map<String, Object>) response2.get('position');
    System.debug('::response3::' + response3);
    Decimal lat = (Decimal) response3.get('lat');
    Decimal longi = (Decimal) response3.get('lng');
      
    a.BillingLatitude = lat;
    a.BillingLongitude = longi;
    update a;
    }
}
```

This works in Salesforce, but Im having issues writing the test class.
This is what I have so far

```
@isTest
public class UpdateBillingCoordinatesTest {
    
    @isTest
    public static void service_call() {

        StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
        mock.setStaticResource('mapsGeoCodemockResponse');
        mock.setStatusCode(200);
        mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
        
        Id patientAccountRecordTypeId = [SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Patient_Account'].Id;
        Account testAccount = new Account(
            RecordTypeId = patientAccountRecordTypeId,
            LastName = 'Test Account',
            PersonMailingStreet = '123 Test Street',
            PersonMailingCity = 'Indianapolis',
            PersonMailingState = 'IN',
            PersonMailingPostalCode = '46201',
            PersonMailingCountry = 'United States'
        );
        
        Test.startTest();
        insert testAccount;
        Test.StopTest();
        
        Account assertAcc = [SELECT Id, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude FROM Account WHERE LastName = 'Test Account' LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('assertAcc' + assertAcc.BillingLatitude);
        System.assertEquals(37.78977, testAccount.BillingLatitude);
    }       
}
```

I made a static resource via setup>static resources>new and just uploaded a file containing the Json as provided by Salesforce ([Salesforce Json Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.maps_developer_guide.meta/maps_developer_guide/maps_apex_geocode.htm))

However I am still getting the error : 'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts'

Am I missing something here?

Comment: In addition to the above, I recommend you read [this Q&A answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334728/using-future-method-in-triggers/334742#334742) as to why you should not use a future from a trigger.

Comment: Mind Phil's recommendation - the given call of `updatePersonAccount` is not even bulkified, i.e. starts a future for each single ID instead of a List.